# Error with error handler in discord.py, too many positional arguments given even though everything given is required

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've been programming a discord bot recently and I've been trying to learn how to use cogs, in my moderation.py cog, there are error handlers for each of the commands, but all of them say too many positional args are given even though all of them are required...

```
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

class ModerationCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


    @commands.command(aliases=['clear','Purge','Clear'])
    @commands.guild_only()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    @commands.bot_has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def purge(self, ctx, amount: int=10):
        deleted = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        await ctx.send("Deleted " + str(amount) + " message on behalf of "+ctx.author.mention.format(ctx.author), delete_after=3)

    @purge.error
    async def purge_handler(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send("You are missing permissions for that -_-".format(ctx.author))
        elif isinstance(error, commands.errors.BotMissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send("I am missing permissions for that -_-")
```

The code just says too many positional args were given for purge_handler.. The error:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: purge_handler() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: I don't see where you call `purge_handler()`, only where it is defined.  It seems there is more code needed to recreate your error.  Could you add this code?

Comment: @Hoog [Error handling](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) is called automatically if an error occurs during command invocation